# C-socket: program of client-server to send a file

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, file-transfer

I am getting confused while sending a file from server to client or client to server. Is this that the only binary file are transferred or bitstream are to be generated? What should be the  format of the text file that is to be send? Is there any specific format?

Comment: There is no format, just bytes, `send()` bytes after `fread()` and  `recv()` bytes before `fwrite()`

Comment: Is it mandatory to convert the text file into binary file in the local drive before sending or "ab" will directly convert to binary in fopen()?